# Git Graph in Visual Studio Code not finding commits

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code

I created a program in Python 3.7 in Visual Studio Code and like using the Git Graph extension to visualize my commits.  When I clicked Git Graph I recieved "Error: Unable to load Commits.  fatal: bad revision HEAD."  I then initialized git and made my first commit.  I received the same error so I unchecked "Show Remote Branches" because I want my repo to be local only.  I then received this message when I initiated Git Graph- "Error: Unable to load commits.  There are no commits in this repository."  I know they're there because I can see them in Gitlense.  I looked online and couldn't find anything that worked.  Git Graph works for all of my other projects.  I also noticed that when I open terminal with my Git Graph tab open, it starts with a path that's different from my project.  I think that Git Graph is looking for my repo, but looking in the wrong place.  Is there a way to change where Git Graph looks or am I missing something?